# Mouseover on div won't change color

Tags: css, html

I'm working on this website and I'm not able to change the menu button on mouseover.
I currently have this div I want to have the mouseover on:

```
<a href="/index.html"><div class="e" id="menu-button"><p id="menu-text">Home</p></div></a>
```

Class e and the ID are bound to this css:

```
#menu-button {
   background-color: azure;
     color: black;
    height: 3.5vw;
    width: 23%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    color: black;
    magin-top: 2%;
    float: left;

}

.e:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

On the 'mouseover' or 'hover' event, the button doesn't change at all.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is happening because of the CSS specificity. `id` >  `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting your div element by ID is more specific than selecting the div element by class, so the `.e:hover` styling is being overriden. Simply change your code to

```
#menu-button {
  background-color: azure;
  color: black;
  height: 3.5vw;
  width: 23%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 2%;
  float: left;
}

#menu-button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `background` of the `.e` element is overridden by the `#menu-button` element.

Use `id` selector. `id` selector have higher priority over `class` selector. So, this will not allow the class selector to override the properties.

```
#menu-button:hover {
    background: blue;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vgms9wL4/)

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
#menu-button {
  background-color: azure;
  color: black;
  height: 3.5vw;
  width: 23%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 2%;
  float: left;
}
#menu-button:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="/index.html">
  <div class="e" id="menu-button">
    <p id="menu-text">Home</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#menu-button:hover` instead. The problem here is [**Specificity of CSS**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). IDs have higher specificity in these cases overwrites the class selector `:hover` property.

**Specificity value**

`#menu-button` 100

`.e` 10

```css
#menu-button {
  background-color: azure;
  color: black;
  height: 3.5vw;
  width: 23%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  color: black;
  magin-top: 2%;
  float: left;
}
#menu-button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="/index.html">
  <div class="e" id="menu-button">
    <p id="menu-text">Home</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

your hover of css class has been overridden by css of id.

#menu-button

try using hover effect on id

```
#menu-button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```